# jQuery DOM array as an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, qtip

I'm working on some HTML pages, and I needed to add some tooltips. Because of the constraints, I chose a Jquery plugin named qtip. I really ain't that good with JavaScript, but I managed to do something that look like the attached picture. (edit : cannot add picture - sorry. But it looks fine ! ;)

For the tooltip content, you can directly put html as the argument. But in the documentation, it says

> You can also pass a **jQuery DOM array** as the argument

([see the related page](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#content))

For several reasons, I'd really like to use this option. 
I've searched the net a bit, but couldn't find how to pass this so called *jQuery DOM array* as the argument.

Code looks like this :

```
$('a[class="someClass"]').qtip({
    content: 'my content here',
    show: 'click',
    hide: 'click',
    (+ other arguments...)
});
```

My question : what exactly is a **jQuery DOM array** and how do I put it as the content argument ?

I'm sure the answer is on the web, but I already lost quite some time looking for it, and I can't really afford to spend 3 days learning JavaScrip just for these tooltips...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what a jQuery DOM array is supposed to be either, but I think what they mean, is that you can use a jQuery object for the content.

```
content: $('#menu li:first')
```

**EDIT**

Actually, scratch my earlier example and try if something like the example above works. I'm guessing that `$(this).attr('alt')` is a bad example, since it anyways returns a string.

Comment: This should work. According to the documentation: "You can also pass a jQuery DOM array as the argument, which will clone the referenced elements and append them to the tooltip content."

Comment: Yeah. The documentation clearly has a problem in this point, since their wording doesn't follow any conventions (or at least any that I'd know about) and they don't seem to provide an example which would clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it says:

> You can also pass a jQuery DOM array
>   as the argument, which will clone the
>   referenced elements and append them to
>   the tooltip content.

Without testing I would risk a guess and if you pass such thing:

```
$('a[class="someClass"]').qtip({
    content: $(".addme"),
    show: 'click',
    ...
```

All elements with class `addme` will be appened to the tooltip, for example if you have this:

```
<span class="addme">Hello</span>
<span class="addme">World</span>
```

"HelloWorld" will be appended to the tooltip contents.

Comment: Yep, you're right =) Just tested it and it works just like you said. Thanks =)